# UnityContainer and internal constructor

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container, internalsvisibleto

I have a class with internal constructor and want to Resolve it from Unity (2.0).

```
public class MyClass {
    internal MyClass(IService service) {
    }
}
```

then I'm doing

```
_container.Resolve<MyClass>();
```

when I do so I have an exception

```
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type MyClass cannot be constructed.
```

IService is registered and the only problem is that constructor is internal.
I really want this class to be public, but I want it to be creatable only via a factory (in which I'm actually calling `container.Resolve<MyClass>()`).

Is there a way to make Unity see that internal constructor? Like InternalsVisibleTo or something?

Comment: Why don't you want to make this ctor public? Are you creating a reusable library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I dug a little into how you might extend Unity for this purpose, and found some interesting information.

First, it seems that Unity selects which constructor to use by internally resolving an `IConstructorSelectorPolicy`. Included in Unity is the `public abstract class ConstructorSelectorPolicyBase<TInjectionConstructorMarkerAttribute>`, which includes this gem:

```
/// <summary>
/// Choose the constructor to call for the given type.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">Current build context</param>
/// <param name="resolverPolicyDestination">The <see cref='IPolicyList'/> to add any
/// generated resolver objects into.</param>
/// <returns>The chosen constructor.</returns>
public SelectedConstructor SelectConstructor(IBuilderContext context, IPolicyList resolverPolicyDestination)
{
    Type typeToConstruct = context.BuildKey.Type;
    ConstructorInfo ctor = FindInjectionConstructor(typeToConstruct) ?? FindLongestConstructor(typeToConstruct);
    if (ctor != null)
    {
        return CreateSelectedConstructor(context, resolverPolicyDestination, ctor);
    }
    return null;
}
```

`FindInjectionConstructor` and company are `private static` methods in this class which ultimately end up calling `Type.GetConstructors` (the overload with no parameters, which only returns `public` constructors). This tells me that if you can arrange for Unity to use your own constructor selector policy, which would be able to select any constructor, you are golden.

There is [good documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660845%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx) about how to make and utilize your own container extensions, so I imagine it's quite possible to make your own `CustomConstructorSelectorPolicy` that includes the relevant portions of [`DefaultUnityConstructorSelectorPolicy`](https://unity.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Unity/Unity/Src/ObjectBuilderCustomization/DefaultUnityConstructorSelectorPolicy.cs) (which derives from the abstract base class and is the default unless you register something else) and [`ConstructorSelectorPolicyBase`](https://unity.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Unity/Unity/Src/ObjectBuilder/Strategies/BuildPlan/Creation/ConstructorSelectorPolicyBase.cs) (deriving from this directly would probably not work well because key methods are not `virtual`, but you can reuse the code).

Therefore I 'd say it's doable with a moderate amount of hassle, but the end result would be quite "pure" from an engineering point of view.

Comment: Here is an example of usage of custom `IConstructorSelectorPolicy` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178464(v=pandp.30).aspx

Answer (score 7):

Unity will only look at public constructors, so you need to make this constructor public.

> I really want this class to be public,
>   but I want it to be creatable only via
>   a factory

In that case, create a factory:

```
public class MyClassFactory : IMyClassFactory
{
    private readonly IService service;

    public MyClassFactory(IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    MyClass IMyClassFactory.CreateNew()
    {
        return new MyClass(this.service);
    }
}
```

And register:

```
_container.Register<IMyClassFactory, MyClassFactory>();
```

And resolve:

```
_container.Resolve<IMyClassFactory>().CreateNew();
```

You can also use Unity's `InjectionFactory`:

```
container.Register<MyClass>(new InjectionFactory(c => 
{   
    return new MyClass(c.Resolve<IService>());
}));
```

For this to work the assembly that holds this code should be able to see the internals of the assembly that holds the `MyClass`. In other words the `MyClass` assembly should be marked with `InternalsVisibleTo`.

What would also work is the following:

```
public static class MyClassFactory
{
    public static MyClass CreateNew(IService service)
    {
        return new MyClass(service);
    }
}

container.Register<MyClass>(new InjectionFactory(c => 
{   
    return MyClassFactory.Create(c.Resolve<IService>());
}));
```

Although you won't have to make the constructor public, it is a great way to obfuscate your code :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's almost exactly what I'm doing :) I just don't like to change that factory every time MyClass dependencies will change. So, searching for a way to do this directly via Unity somehow

Answer (score 3):

Just make the class internal and the constructor public...

1. Interface public
2. Class internal
3. Constructor of class public.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible there are workarounds/hacks that would allow you to do this with Unity 9I don't know if any), but in general if you want a class to be managed by Unity (or any IOC container), it needs to be public with a public constructor.

One option might be to make an abstract factory that creates the class that has a public constructor, and keep the class's constructor internal.  The downside is then your factory will be managed by Unity, but your class itself will not.

Comment: "it needs to be public with a public constructor." - that is wrong, Unity works perfectly with internal classes with public constructors. That is the case when I want to manage my internal dependencies with IoC.   What I've done is an abstract factory. And within it I want to create an instance of MyClass. I can do new MyClass(_container.Resolve<IService>()), but don't want to do it manually.