# Do I have to declare variables public to use [Dependency] with Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-container

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;   
..
..
public class ContentsController : BaseController
{
    [Dependency]
    public IContentService contentService { get; set; }

}
```

I am using Unity to give me an instance of IContentService. However it will only work if I declare this to be public. If I declare private then it _cs is null?

Is the only way I can get this to work by declaring it public ?

Can I declare the IContentService in the controller constructor? If I did that then can someone show me the best syntax and how I would connect this up to a private variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the part about constructor injection:

```cs
public class ContentsController : BaseController
{
  private readonly IContentService service;
  public ContentsController(IContentService service)
  {
    if(service == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("service");
    this.service = service;
  }
}

var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IContentService, MyContentService>();
var controller = container.Resolve<ContentsController>();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is allready answer here:
[Unity framework DependencyAttribute only works for public properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473575/unity-framework-dependencyattribute-only-works-for-public-properties) 
You have to declare variables public to make this attribute work as you expect it to.